# How to create nanohttpd server in android?

Tags: android, http, nanohttpd

Actually ,I had searched some questions and go to the github. But I'm new ,I cannot understand the example.

I want to create the http server in android so I can access it in PC browser.

I had instance a class extend nanohttpd, but the server just don't work. I don't know why ,my computer and phone are in the same WIFI,uh.....

```
public class MyHTTPD extends NanoHTTPD {

     /**
     * Constructs an HTTP server on given port.
     */
    public MyHTTPD()throws IOException {
        super(8080);
    }


@Override
    public Response serve( String uri, Method method,
            Map<String, String> header, Map<String, String> parms,
            Map<String, String> files )
    {
        System.out.println( method + " '222" + uri + "' " );
        String msg = "<html><body><h1>Hello server</h1>\n";
        if ( parms.get("username") == null )
            msg +=
                "<form action='?' method='get'>\n" +
                "  <p>Your name: <input type='text' name='username'></p>\n" +
                "</form>\n";
        else
            msg += "<p>Hello, " + parms.get("username") + "!</p>";

        msg += "</body></html>\n";
        return new NanoHTTPD.Response(msg );
    }


    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        try
        {
            new MyHTTPD();
        }
        catch( IOException ioe )
        {
            System.err.println( "Couldn't start server:\n" + ioe );
            System.exit( -1 );
        }
        System.out.println( "Listening on port 8080. Hit Enter to stop.\n" );
        try { System.in.read(); } catch( Throwable t ) {
            System.out.println("read error");
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: Which version of nanohttpd do you use ?

Answer (score 11):

Your sample code is missing one small detail - you create the server but you never call the "start()" method which kicks it off to listen for incoming connections.  In your main() method, you could write

```
        (new MyHTTPD()).start();
```

and all would be well, your server would respond the way you hoped it would.

The reason it works that way is twofold: I want the constructor to be a cheap, inexpensive operation, without side-effects.  For instance, while unit testing, I call "start()" in the *setup* and "stop()" in the *teardown* methods of my jUnit test.

Comment: sir please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055743/android-webserver-shows-html-pages-as-text

Answer (score 0):

This is the code working for me, but I have different version of NANOHTTPD, I don't have time right now to test out your solution. Here is UploadServer class and Nano class. I return file-upload.htm from sdcard/Discover Control/Web path

```
public class UploadServer extends NanoHTTPD {
public UploadServer() throws IOException {
    super(8080, new File("."));
}

public Response serve( String uri, String method, Properties header, Properties parms, Properties files ) {
    File rootsd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File path = new File(rootsd.getAbsolutePath() + "/Discover Control/Web");
    Response r = super.serveFile("/file-upload.htm", header, path, true);
    return r;
}
}
```

NanoHttpd class

[NanoHTTPD.java](http://www.fileswap.com/dl/he7dGdELl0/)

FILE UPLOAD

[file-upload.htm](http://www.fileswap.com/dl/RGMXBzBMW4/)

Hope this helps and enjoy your work.

Comment: The Link for file-upload.htm seems to be dead. Could you please re-upload it?

Comment: Also, the method serveFile() doesn't work and gives the error. `The method serveFile(String, Properties, File, boolean) is undefined for the type MainActivity` How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Android Activities have a [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html) and do not use a `main()` function.

If you want to start and stop  the webserver as part of the Activity then you need call start and stop 
in `onPause` and `onResume`, ie

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private MyHTTPD mServer;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

       try {
            mServer = new MyHTTPD();
            mServer.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            mServer = null;
        }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(mServer != null) {
            mServer.stop();
            mServer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

An alternative is to implement the webserver as part of a Service.

In an app I'm working I have a requirement to keep the webserver running even if the user leaves the app. The only way to do this is to start and stop the webserver as part of a long-running Service that is not bound to the Activity. See [Vogella's great tutorial on Android Services](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html).

Answer (score 0):

This code working for fine viewing html pages with css class which are in my assesst folders

```
androidWebServer.start();
```

this will start the server below code for server functions

```
public class AndroidWebServer extends NanoHTTPD {

Realm realm;

Map<String, String> parms;
DBHelper db = new DBHelper(OpenRAP.getContext());
boolean isStartedHS = MainActivity.isStartedHS;
private AsyncHttpServer server = new AsyncHttpServer();
private AsyncServer mAsyncServer = new AsyncServer();
private String TAG = "androidwebserver";
Storage storage = new Storage(OpenRAP.getContext());
public AndroidWebServer(int port) {
    super(port);
}


public AndroidWebServer(String hostname, int port) {
    super(hostname, port);
}


@Override
public String getHostname() {
    return super.getHostname();
}


@Override
public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
    Method method = session.getMethod();
    String uri = session.getUri();
    Map<String, String> files = new HashMap<>();
    SharedPreferences prefs = OpenRAP.getContext().getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.mypreference, MODE_PRIVATE);
    OpenRAP app = (OpenRAP) OpenRAP.getContext();
    Storage storage = new Storage(OpenRAP.getContext());
    String currentpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/www/";
    String temp = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/www/temp/";
    String ecarpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/www/ecars_files/";
    String xcontent = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/www/xcontent/";
    String Endpoint = session.getUri();
    if (Endpoint.equals("/")) {

        String answer = "";
        try {
            // Open file from SD Card
            File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile();
            FileReader index = new FileReader(root +
                    "/www/openrap/index.html");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(index);
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                answer += line;
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.w("Httpd", ioe.toString());
        }
        return newFixedLengthResponse(answer);
    }
```