# How to enable USB debugging in Android?

Tags: android

How do you enable USB debugging in the Nexus 7 (first generation)?

Edit:
The accepted answer applies to other android devices also where Developer option is hidden .

Answer (score 221, accepted):

Toggle on "USB Debugging" in the "Developer Options" area of Settings.

If you do not see "Developer Options", go into "About device" in Settings and tap on the "Build number" entry seven times, which will unlock "Developer Options".

As documented on Android Developers: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html

Comment: Thanks.. Tapping the build number made me a developer.. :)

Comment: @Tarun: Personally, I'd've gone with an Android programming trivia question ("Which of the following is not an Android class? A) `TextView` B) `PackageManager` C) `UINavigationController` D) `Html`"). :-)

Comment: and where on earth is this documented ?

Comment: 'tap on the "Build number" entry seven times'... I thought you were kidding!

Comment: @SimonArnold: Of course not. I never kid. BTW, I hope you followed the instructions in my answer while standing inside a pentagram made of dried bat blood, to ward of the demons that might be unleashed when you make The Seventh Tap. :-)

Comment: Odd I did that tapping on the build number on a Z1 and it worked, but it does not work on my Nexus 7 oO. It's a multi-user device, could this be a problem? I am not declared as the owner of the tablet but just a normal user. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Zainodis: AFAIK, developer mode is only for the owner, not other accounts.

Comment: @CommonsWare Unfortunately you're right xD thanks for answering. By now I tried enabling the Developer options on the main account - but they're still not available on my normal user account which really is a bummer :/

Comment: LOL this is new on new Android version. I remembered that there is even a "Developer option" in Settings without doing anything.

Comment: Here is a helpful link: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: @2cupsOfTech - https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html

Answer (score 16):

do this

**1)** go to settings

**2)** go to developers setting

**3)** enable developers setting by turning the switch on top of the page.

**4)** select Usb Debugging.

**Note:** if developer option is not available then Tap 7 times on the build version button to unlock developer options...

Comment: Nexus 7 do not have developer settings.. Answer by CommonsWare is correct.

Comment: then tap 7 times on build number i forgot to write in my answre

Comment: @Tarun please upvote this question i have got a question ban  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081046/android-web-server-not-supported-by-firefox

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you have to check Do you have unlocked developer option or not? If not then you can unlock it by clicking on "Build number" 7 times where you can found this "Build number" option in Setting -> About Phone

After then open Developer option which is available second last option in setting page. Check in Usb Debuging. you will get dialog which show you approvance for Usb debuging for separate computer.

Steps For Usb Debuging

1. Open setting in Phone
2. Open Developer Option
3. Enable developers Option by Clicking 7 times on "Build Number"
4. Check Usb Debugging.