# Unable to set up ADB with Motorola X Developer's edition Windows 7

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, motorola

This has been an entertaining 3 hours. I am trying to set up the ADB for my Moto X gen 1 Developer's edition so I can begin to learn android development with Android Studio(I have 2 years of Java knowledge). I first tried using the google ADB driver, which windows said wasn't a compatible driver. I was guided to install the [Motorola Device Manager](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481), which apparently held the correct driver. Well that worked splendidly. My computer still sees my phone as a "Portable device" and is listed as such in the device manager, not as it should be under the ADB. I have already double and triple checked that my phone is in USB debugging mode. Using android 5.1.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGo8o.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uo9Im.png

Does anyone know what is going on here? I'm desperate. I spent an hour on the phone with Motorola customer support and they had no clue what I was talking about.

Comment: start with enabling `USB Debugging` in the `Developer options`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable USB debugging in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103117/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-in-android)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. USB debugging is enabled and running properly as far as the phone is concerned.

Comment: I do not think I would trust your expertise on this subject http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/adb-device-detection-in-windows.html

Comment: I wouldn't trust it either. Not a great hardware guy. Indeed I am getting no response from the given command, although my phone clearly states USB debugging connected and my computer sees and is able to read data from the phone. It is seen as a "Portable device" in explorer.

Comment: Ahah! Set my phone as a camera (PTP) in connection settings and it is now seeing the device. Geez that's strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the USB connection settings from MTP to PTP and it suddenly worked. Thanks, Motorola. LOL.