# Android adb backup storage issue

Tags: android, adb

I have problem with **adb bakup** on my android phone - it is Lenovo Vibe Shot Z90a40, Android version **5.1**. I'm trying to backup Viber, but the problem happens for other packages and full backup too. The size of produced **.ab** file is always about 40 bytes.

I've created **.bat** script where executing **logcat** to see what happens in device:

```
@echo off
echo Connecting.
"%~dp0adb" version
"%~dp0adb" kill-server
"%~dp0adb" wait-for-device

"%~dp0adb" shell am force-stop com.viber.voip

echo Enter Backup My Data on Android phone screen.
"%~dp0adb" backup -f "%~dp0viber.ab" com.viber.voip

ping -n 10 127.0.0.1>nul 
"%~dp0adb" shell logcat -d > "%~dp0log.txt"
"%~dp0adb" kill-server

echo "press any key to exit." 
pause
```

I see in the log error message which tells that there is not enough free space:

```
I/BackupManagerService( 1136): --- Performing full-dataset adb backup ---

I/BackupManagerService( 1136): Initiating bind of OBB service on com.android.server.backup.BackupManagerService$FullBackupObbConnection@3bc92971

W/ContextImpl( 1136): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.bindService:1809 com.android.server.backup.BackupManagerService$FullBackupObbConnection.establish:2998 com.android.server.backup.BackupManagerService$PerformAdbBackupTask.run:3620 java.lang.Thread.run:818 <bottom of call stack> 

E/Cryptfs (  304): not running with encryption, aborting

I/BackupManagerService( 1136): OBB service connection com.android.internal.backup.IObbBackupService$Stub$Proxy@22da70c4 connected on com.android.server.backup.BackupManagerService$FullBackupObbConnection@3bc92971

D/BackupManagerService( 1136): Binding to full backup agent : com.viber.voip

W/BackupManagerService( 1136): ensureAvailableSpace 

D/BackupStrogeUtils( 1136):  freeCacheStorage bytes=230686720

D/BackupStrogeUtils( 1136):  freeCacheStorage Start bytes:230686720

D/BackupStrogeUtils( 1136):  listFilesRecursive start uid=1000

D/BackupStrogeUtils( 1136):  listFilesRecursive file = /cache/recovery/last_log_r file.stat.st_uid=0

D/BackupStrogeUtils( 1136):  listFilesRecursive file = /cache/recovery/last_install file.stat.st_uid=0

D/BackupStrogeUtils( 1136):  listFilesRecursive file = /cache/recovery/last_locale file.stat.st_uid=0

D/BackupStrogeUtils( 1136):  freeCacheStorage Found 0 on cache

D/BackupStrogeUtils( 1136):  freeCacheStorage End 

D/BackupStrogeUtils( 1136): Not enough free space; 230686720 requested, 220848128 available

D/BackupManagerService( 1136): backupOnePackage ensureAvailableSpace failed : com.viber.voip

D/BackupManagerService( 1136): Full backup processing complete.

D/bu      (26755): Finished.
```

But I have a lot of free space on device. I executed **df** command:

```
@echo off
"%~dp0adb" kill-server
"%~dp0adb" shell df > df.txt
"%~dp0adb" kill-server
echo Done!
pause
```

And here is result:

```
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
Filesystem               Size     Used     Free   Blksize

/dev                     1.4G    76.0K     1.4G   4096

/sys/fs/cgroup           1.4G    12.0K     1.4G   4096

/mnt/asec                1.4G     0.0K     1.4G   4096

/mnt/obb                 1.4G     0.0K     1.4G   4096

/system                  1.9G     1.7G   255.5M   4096

/data                   25.4G    12.3G    13.1G   4096

/preload               387.4M   127.5M   259.9M   4096

/cache                 248.0M   220.0K   247.7M   4096

/persist                27.5M   184.0K    27.3M   4096

/firmware               64.0M    51.1M    12.9M   16384

/mnt/shell/emulated     25.3G    12.3G    13.1G   4096

/storage/emulated/legacy    25.3G    12.3G    13.1G   4096

/storage/sdcard0        25.3G    12.3G    13.1G   4096
```

I have almost 13GB free on **/data** partition. The strange situation is that backup restore function works, I successfully transferred viber package from my old phone to this phone.

I found similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482042/adb-backup-does-not-work) and made tests with both versions **1.0.31** and **1.0.32** of adb, but the result is the same.
Does anyone has an idea what is wrong ?
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: No, still no solution

Comment: Look for the adb version of your **device**. Enter in the shell of the device and do `adb version`. If the version is prior to 1.0.32, use adb 1.0.31 on your machine. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Backup started working for me after quoting the parameters for ADB as described in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482042/adb-backup-does-not-work).

e.g.:

> adb backup "-apk -shared -all -f backup.ab"

I did use 1.0.31, but it might not have been the factor.