# Adb backup does not work on my HarmonyOS 2.0 phone

Tags: android, adb, huawei-mobile-services, harmonyos

When I tried to back up my app data, it doesn't work. Specs are listed below:

- Huawei mate 10
- HarmonyOS 2.0.0
- version: 2.0.0.230

I just run

```
adb backup -f phi.ab -noapk -noshared -nosystem com.PigeonGames.Phigros
```

when the app that I want to backup is open. But my phone doesn't even display the "full backup" interface.

My computer shows:

```
C:\Users\BingHeng\Desktop>adb backup -f phi.ab -noapk -noshared -nosystem com.PigeonGames.Phigros
WARNING: adb backup is deprecated and may be removed in a future release
Now unlock your device and confirm the backup operation...
```

Then nothing. It just creat a backup file with 0 byte.

I am sure that my mobile phone has been connected to the computer, and all other ADB commands can be used normally. Like "adb install", it can be used.

I don't know what I should do now.

Comment: There is a similar question and you can see if it helps： https://stackoverflow.com/q/34482042/13329100

Comment: I see, but it didn't help.

Comment: Have you unlocked your phone and checked if an interface shows up? Have you tried closing and stopping the app from running in the background before initiating the backup?

Comment: I am sure that I have unlocked my phone and opened the app that I want to backup.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have found the problem.
Just delete the app named "冰箱" I had installed before.