# Android studio can't see my phone (Vodafone Smart Prime 6)

Tags: android, sdk, adb

I am trying to test my app to my phone which is a Vodafone Smart Prime 6 one. Unfortunately,Android Studio can't see it. I used all the adb techniques plus restarting the phone multiple times,but still no result. I don't have any problems with my old Samsung S3 phone.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What are 'all the adb techniques' (please, add to the question, not as a comment :)  )

Comment: adb kill-server,adb start-server. That's what I was meaning. Maybe the new preview version of Android Studio,is causing the problem(Android Studio 2.0 Preview 4),but I doubt it.

Comment: are u working on windows..? did u checked device manager ? is your device drivers are properly installed.?

Comment: Yes I am working in Windows 8.1. I also checked the device manager. The drivers installed are from this site http://androidmtk.com/download-vodafone-usb-drivers

Comment: It worked:). Thanks.

Comment: @ It worked:) - interesting !

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the "USB Debugging Mode" after enabling "Developer Options

Check this post for more details :: [Enabling USB Debugging Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103117/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-in-android)

Comment: I did that. I am allowed to use the phone as a developer. But nothing happens within Android Studio.