# How do I install an APK without any internet connection?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, file-manager

My phone's antenna died so it can't connect to the internet by cellular or wi-fi but I still want to use the phone for portable entertainment. I need a way to install an app strictly through the USB connection.

Unfortunately, every article I've looked at for how to install APKs without Google Play tells me to start by getting a file manager from Google Play.

Comment: You should ask this on http://www.android.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two way can do that:

Note: you have to connect phone with PC througth USB cable before.

1. Copy any apk to phone from your PC/latop and open file browser in phone to open apk which you want to install
2. Use can use ADB command line tool:
   Type command: adb install [apk_name_with_full_path]
   Ex: `adb install C:\your_package.apk`

Answer (score 0):

You can download APKs on your PC and install it using following command:

**adb install -r [apk path]**

Note: make sure that you have adb utility in your PC and in your phone developer options is switched on with USB Debugging enabled.

[Enable USB Debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103117/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-in-android)

Comment: The adb utility was the answer, thank you for your help.