# Android Bluetooth Low Energy: Not hearing advertisements on some devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, nexus-7

I have a device that is emitting Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) advertisements and a Nexus 7 (2013) Android tablet that should hear those advertisements. However, it cannot hear the BLE advertisements from my device and appears not to hear any BLE advertisements (there are some BLE beacons in the area). The same goes with a ca. 2014 Moto G phone I tried.

However, an LG G4, a Samsung S4 and a Samsung S5 will pick upp precisely those advertisements.

Is there potentially some configuration I can modify for the Nexus 7 2013 device so it can hear those BLE advertisements? My internet survey suggests that the Nexus 7 2013 is BLE capable (as opposed to the Nexus 7 2012 which isn't).

Is there some way to detect (e.g. via some API) whether a given device can listen to BLE advertisements?

EDIT:
Tried this on a different Nexus 7 and it worked there. For reference I'm using this app to search for BLE advertisements: https://github.com/gardarh/android-blescanner

Comment: What API level do your problematic devices use?

Comment: It's classic but have you tried switching off bluetooth and turning on again? Moto G used to have the bug when Beacons are around system bluetooth crashes and the fix was to switch it off and on again.

Comment: I just tried this on a different Nexus 7 2013 and sure enough, it is picking up BLE probes. I guess I need to take better look at the other Nexus 7. Btw.  I'm running the latest possible version on the Nexus 7 devices (Android 6).

Comment: It's worth looking if the Nexus 7 is actually "seeing" any BLE adv. packets.
Enable Developer options on your Nexus 7 (see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103117/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-in-android)) and press the "Enable Bluetooth HCI snoop log"
to enable realtime sniffing. Disable it after a while and search for "bthci_snoop.log" file (usually in /storage/emulated/0). Open it in Wireshark and look for BLE adv. packets.

Comment: Good point Tomer! The hci log indicates that the device is in fact receiving all the advertisements but not delivering them upwards (the log is here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18637933/btsnoop_hci.log ). Where can they be stopped? My kernel version is 3.4.0-gad29d11 and build no. MOB30X .

Comment: Could it be, that the location service is disabled? (The one in the settings)

Comment: @p2pkit: Yes, that was it! Please post your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to activate location in the settings to receive ble scan results on Android 6+

Comment: Note that even though your app has the location permissions that is not enough by itself. If the location service is disabled the Bluetooth Low Energy scan will just "silently not work".