# Emulator doesn't work: Apps can't be executed

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm new in android studio. There is a problem: I cannot execute my app in emulator. When I create a new project, I choose Basic Activity. As you know, there is text 'hello world' and I also can exec that without any code changed. But when emulator exec, didn't show anything!

1. No USB devices or running emulators detected: I'm googled about that. But another people said that problem could ignore.

2.May I change build types variable in Open Module settings?

Here is emulator executing. Nothing happened!
[image]

Please help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you create any virtual device yet?

If you do it, then you can try empty activity.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use `Invalidate cache and restart`option of Android Studio.

If does not work, update `System Image` to latest version and restart your IDE.(If It's updated to latest version, download an older version and test it.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your app on the emulator then you need to first set it up.
Here are the steps to setup emulator :

1. Go to AVD Manager.
   [image]
2. Create a New Virtual Device
   [image]
3. Choose Device Specifications
   [image]
4. Choose the System Image which you want to install in that emulator. You need to download the system images if you had not downloaded them yet.
   [image]
5. Choose Device Hardware Specifications
   [image]
6. And Than Click on Finish. Android Studio automatically generates Emulater for you.
   [image]
7. Open AVD Manager Again And you will see an emulater. Just run it and you will able to install your app

Comment: I am add a picture. And I also reinstall android studio. Nothing changed.

Comment: Do you have SDK Tools 26.1.1 or higher

Comment: According to documentation, Also try to re-setup Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (Intel HAXM). As it also creates the same problem as you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can try to:

- `Make sure in your phone is enable the settings "Debug USB"` [Here the instructions](https://support.honeywellaidc.com/s/article/How-to-enable-USB-Debug-Developer-Options-on-an-Android-device) or from stack overflow [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103117/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-in-android)
- `install drivers/tools from SDK Manager (You can find sdk manager in top left of the screen with the icon of a cube with an arrow down) in the menu "SDK Tools"`

[image]

If this can't solve your problem, i suggest to:

- `Install the emulator again from SDK Manager`

And in extremely way:

- `install android studio again`