# Debug directly on the device through Visual Studio in a MAUI project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, maui

I have a C# MAUI project and the option to debug directly on the Android device does not appear in it.

[image]

Does anyone know what needs to be done to make the option to debug directly on the device appear?

The option to debug directly on the device appears.

Comment: Did you checkout the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/device/setup

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103117/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-in-android

Comment: Thank TheTanic! Turn on and turn off the "USB debugging" solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Just as TheTanic said that [Enable USB debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/device/setup).

Here are the steps to open the USB debugging mode.

After enabling developer mode on your device, enable USB debugging by following these steps:

1. Go to the Settings screen.
2. Select Developer options.
3. Turn on the USB debugging option.

Depending on the UI your device is running, the USB debugging option may be in a different location. Consult your device documentation if you can't find USB debugging.